# If number is = to 25

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have a text field that a user can enter a number and if the number is correct it the displays "image a" and if incorrect displays "image b" below the text field i  want them to have as many tries as they like to get it correct. The only thing i have found so far is this?

sorry about the lack of experience guys :(

```
var my_string = prompt("Please enter a number","");
document.write(my_string)
if(isNaN(my_string)){
document.write ("this is not a number ");
}else{document.write ("this is a number ");
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? The asawyer answer seems correct if u want to compare a number.

Comment: If you're really worried about receiving in a number (or want the ability to compare and answer back "too long"/"too high", I'd look in to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user will enter *characters*, so you'll have to compare strings. You can use the `===` operator which checks equality; you'll have to check against the string `"25"`.

Then, to display the image, you'll have to give the images in HTML an ID. After doing so, you can fetch the element in JavaScript using `document.getElementById("some_id")`. Showing/hiding is done using `element.style.display = "block"` vs `"none"`.

Answer (score 2):

Heres code sniplet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_number()
{
   var num = document.getElementById('input_number').value;
   var img = num == '25' ? 'good.png' : 'bad.png';
   document.getElementById('result_image').src = img;
   document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="input_number"
<input type="submit" onclick="check_number();return false;">

<div id="result" style="display:none;">
   <img src="blank.png" alt="" id="result_image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started

```
var my_string = prompt("Please enter a number","");
document.write(my_string);

if(my_string === '25'){
    document.write('Yesss');
} else {
    document.write('Wrong');
}
```

Comment: `my_string === 25` will be more accurate.

Comment: @Pranav This is one of the reason's I love coffeescript so much, `==` and `is` become `===` automatically.